# Ssh  в PyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm, ssh, jetbrains

Хочу использовать для своего проекта JetBrains PyCharm 1.0.1. Скачал, поставил. Я работаю в среде Windows XP, а код находится на Linux сервере без иксов. Пытался найти как создать ssh-соединение в PyCharm, так и не нашел. Кто нибудь может подсказать, как настроить PyCharm на работу через shh?

Answer (score 2):

Доступно с версии 1.1

[You can set up "Remote Hosts" to be FTP, SFTP, etc. PyCharm can open projects from such remote location and autoupload files from the IDE once they are saved.](http://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/whatsnew/)

ssh, судя по всему, должен поддерживаться. вот соответствующий [баг](http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/PY-2234).

Answer (score 1):

UPD: простите, я не так понял вопрос.

Если IDE стоит на компьютере с Windows XP, то достаточно примонтировать каким-либо образом папку с сервера на клиентский компьютер. Если она доступна только по ssh, могу посоветовать коммерческий продукт [ExpanDrive](http://www.expandrive.com/) и открытый [Dokan SSHFS](http://dokan-dev.net/en/) . Если есть возможность открыть доступ по CIFS (Samba) или FTP, в Windows есть поддержка их монтирования.
После того, как сетевой диск будет примонтирован, IDE сможет работать с проектом как с любым другим.

Comment: IDE стоит на компьютере с Wiondows XP и я хочу подключиться к Linux по ssh. На Linux лежат исходники.